# Is there a way to understand if a Job<Void> completed successfully?

Tags: java, playframework

In Play, it seems that if an exception is thrown inside a `Job<T>`, the exception does not propagate outward.

If I understand correctly, in order to know if the inner code throws an exception, I must revert to using boolean return values ([a known anti pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-error-code-with-exception))? Or am I missing something?

Here is a code sample that does not throw anything, but rather renders the todo page - and I would like to know how to know the inner job threw an exception from the outer controller method:

```
public static void testException() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    F.Promise<Void> result = new Job<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void doJob() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            throw new RuntimeException("Foo");
        }
    }.now();
    await(result);
    result.get();
    todo();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just using a `Job<Boolean>` instead and returning `true` on success.

Answer (score 0):

I think await expects the method called inside to return Promise which is a Future (result will be captured when the execution is completed). Its async, so throwing an exception outward won't make much sense.

If you just do a get() on the result, it would give you any exceptions there were (it will throw). See [code](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/libs/F.java)

Comment: See my updated question - I tried using `get()`, but this still does not throw an exception.

Comment: Also, I believe that if I dropped the call to `await()` all together, the job would execute on the web server thread pool, which is not a good idea.

Comment: i think you are right in calling await, no problem with that. Just that when I look at the code for Promise, it conveys to me that get should throw an exception if there was one, weird it doesn't in your case. may be you want to try the play google group?

Comment: Thanks, I already sent a link to this question to the group. When I debugged the `await()` I saw the exception was being swallowed somewhere (and logged), but didn't see a way to access it from the outside.